# JavaScript - Trying to figure out why my average sum isn't working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, average

Trying to work out why my code block isn't working to calculate the average of my array. Hoping a fresh set of eyes can tell me why it's not doing the math's. 
Can I also just add that "mark" is an array which doesn't hold any integers and the numbers are stored in the console as opposed to be stored in the array it's-self. I am trying to get it to work through user input, when the user input's the mark into an input box and take the values stored in the console.

```
function getTotal() {
  let total = 0;
  let count = 0;
  let i = 0;


  for (let i = 0; i < mark.length; i++) {
    total += mark.length[i];
  }
  if (mark[i] !== undefined) {
    //legit value//
    count++;
    total += mark[i];
  }
  let avg = total / count;
  console.log(avg)

}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " The Average is " + total;
document.getElementById("Average").addEventListener("click", getTotal);
```

Comment: Where is `mark` coming from?

Comment: You're setting the innerHTML before the method is ever called....  And `total` is scoped to the method.  It will not exist outside the method.

Comment: Move the setting of the innerHTML *into* the method

Answer (score 0):

Sum the numbers in the array, and then divide by the array's length. If the array's length is `0`, return `NaN` (or throw an error):

```js
function getAverage(arr) {
  if (!arr.length) return NaN; // handler empty array case
  
  let total = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    total += arr[i];
  }
    
  return total / arr.length;
}

console.log(getAverage([2, 2, 2]));
console.log(getAverage([10, 20, 33]));
console.log(getAverage([]));
```

When you want to use the method in your code, create an event listener:

```
document.getElementById("Average").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const average = getAverage(mark);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " The Average is " + average ;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet

```js
function getTotal(mark) {
  let total = 0;
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < mark.length; i++) {
    total += mark[i];
    count++;
  }

  let avg = total / count;
  console.log(avg)

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " The Average is " + avg;
}

document.getElementById("Average").addEventListener("click", () => {
  getTotal([90, 96, 100, 98])
});
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<button type="button" id="Average">Get Total</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

mark.length[i] should probably be mark[i], also the if statement is outside of your for loop so it only ever checks the last index.

Usually when you have a "get" method you should return something. Also not sure where mark comes from so I made this snippet below to help ya out.

Also "document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " The Average is " + total;" should be inside the function.

```js
let mark = [1,2,3,4,5]

function getTotal() {
  let items = mark.filter(n => n !== undefined)
  let total = items.reduce((sum, n) => sum + n, 0)
  let average = total / items.length
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " The Average is " + average;
}

document.getElementById("Average").addEventListener("click", getTotal);
```

```html
<buttton id="Average">Get Average</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```